# How to send sms message inside broadcast receiver class?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a class that implements a broadcast receiver. I also inside of this class i want to be able to send a text message out automatically. Is this possible. Ive tried a lot of different things and nothing seems to work. Maybe im doing something wrong. But here is my source code that i have so far.

```
public class smsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private  MainActivity main;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, smsReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    String str = "";
    String phonenumber = "";
    String houseNumber ="22";
    String message = "Two bedrooms Two Baths";

        SmsMessage []msgs = null;
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();   
        if(bundle != null){
        Object[]pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i2=0; i2<msgs.length; i2++){

        msgs[i2]= SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i2]);
        phonenumber +=  msgs[i2].getOriginatingAddress();


        str += msgs[i2].getMessageBody().toString();



        }




        sms.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, pi, null);



    }



    }

}
```

If i am doing anything wrong please let me know. Thanks everyone in advance.

Logcat errors

06-26 15:49:57.357: ERROR/ContactsProvider(175): Cannot determine the default account for contacts compatibility

06-26 15:49:57.357: ERROR/ContactsProvider(175): android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure

06-26 15:49:57.357: ERROR/ContactsProvider(175):     at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:1437)

06-26 15:49:57.357: ERROR/ContactsProvider(175):     at android.accounts.AccountManager.access$400(AccountManager.java:138)

06-26 15:49:57.357: ERROR/ContactsProvider(175):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)

06-26 15:49:57.357: ERROR/ContactsProvider(175):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

There is all my errors.

Answer (score 3):

Does your AndroidManifest.xml include the [SEND_SMS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SEND_SMS) permission?

EDIT: try this and see if it prints anything out:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, smsReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    String str = "";
    String phonenumber = "";
    String houseNumber ="22";
    String message = "Two bedrooms Two Baths";
try{
        SmsMessage []msgs = null;
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();   
        if(bundle != null){
        Object[]pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i2=0; i2<msgs.length; i2++){

        msgs[i2]= SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i2]);
        phonenumber +=  msgs[i2].getOriginatingAddress();


        str += msgs[i2].getMessageBody().toString();



        }




        sms.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, pi, null);
}
}catch(Exception e1){
    android.util.Log.v("SMS ERROR","Exception sending SMS ["+e1.getMessage()+"]", e1);
}
}
```

Comment: @Femi Yes is does send and receive....Everytime i run the program it force closes after i receive a message.

Comment: If it force closes then you must have an error in the android logs: add your error log output to your question.

Comment: 06-26 15:49:57.357: ERROR/ContactsProvider(175):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)

Comment: Ah, well, the code you have posted is not accessing the ContactsProvider at all so it is a little odd that a failure in the ContactsProvider will cause a force close in your application. Are you doing anything in `MainActivity` with the ContactsProvider?

Comment: @Femi I know... Idk what to do man.. Idk what is causing this. If i remove the SmsManager code and just have it diplay a toast message with the text message then it works.But for some reason it does want to take the SmsManager to send a text.

Comment: I'd almost suggest you have a null pointer exception somewhere: maybe you're receiving an Intent that doesn't have the necessary extras. What happens if you wrap all the SmsManager code in a try/catch block and log the exception?

Comment: Can you give me an example of that from what i have above?

Comment: @Femi I just tried it out. It doesnt force close now but now when i receive  a text nothing happens. it doesnt send another text.

Comment: You should be able to look in the log output for the error with the tag SMS ERROR and see what is going wrong.

Comment: @Femi How do i loom at the log output??

Comment: Ah, if you're in Eclipse then the log output should be in the debug view. Alternatively **adb logcat** at the command line should do it.

Comment: @Femi, i would like to know when the SMS has been sent and when the SMS has been delivered inside your code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Put this block inside of your broadcast receiver file.

```
String phonenumber = "123456789";
String message     = "Message";
 SmsMessage []msgs = null;
  SmsManager sms   = SmsManager.getDefault();
  sms.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, null, null);
```

You'll need to place this next to your imports in the same file:

```
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
```

You will also need this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

I hope this helps!