# Android broadcast receiver error when sending text message

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am working on an app that detects an incoming phone call and sends a text message to the originating phone number in response.

This is the setup:

Background process registers phone call receiver
Phone call receiver accesses static method within an Activity
This static method sends the SMS message (the method is pictured below)

```
public static void sendSms(String phonenumber)
    {
    String message = autoText;
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

I've pinpointed my error to that last line -- it causes the program to crash with an "Error receiving broadcast intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } in .... phone call receiver.

I've been searching for hours and have no clue why this built-in function to send SMS messages should be breaking everything.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks Stack Overflow.

Comment: Post your full logcat error log here....

Comment: see this link,this may help you-[send mgs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484807/how-to-send-sms-message-inside-broadcast-receiver-class?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Add in your Manifest the SEND_SMS permission as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```